# django: manage.py migrate won't migrate newly installed app

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to use [django-djconfig](http://django-djconfig.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html).

I've followed the instructions, and added it to my INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django-djconfig',
    'grappelli',

    #default apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    ...
```

But when I run `./manage.py migrate` I get this:

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: datetimewidget, haystack, grappelli, allauth, crispy_forms, webdesign, staticfiles, django_summernote, messages
  Apply all migrations: prerequisites, suggestions, comments, announcements, quest_manager, sessions, notifications, courses, auth, sites, contenttypes, account, badges, socialaccount, profile_manager, admin
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Results of `pip freeze`

```
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
decorator==4.0.2
defusedxml==0.4.1
Django==1.8.2
django-allauth==0.21.0
django-crispy-forms==1.4.0
django-datetime-widget==0.9.3
django-djconfig==0.5.0
django-grappelli==2.7.1
...
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It says in the docs to add 'djconfig' not 'django-djconfig' to INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: I'm a dumb-ass.  I was editing a copy of settings.py, not the one being used =P

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `./manage.py makemigrations` first? If there aren't any existing migrations, django won't create any tables.